# What can you do to make your beamer presentation look great?

Tags: latex, look-and-feel, beamer

I just arrived at [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/) page.
It is both simple to implement and looks great.
I'm looking for more such examples.

Answer (score 11):

You already hit a gold mine with [texample](http://www.texample.net).

A couple of obvious tips:

- The [TikZ manual](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) contains all kinds of gorgeous examples of drawing with LaTeX
- The [beamer homepage](http://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/overview) contains some [beamer examples](http://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/src/tip/examples/) to demonstrate its power. The beamer manual is also full of examples.

So: texample, TikZ manual, beamer manual. There is no other good resource that I'm aware of for LaTeX presentations.

**Update**: there is also the [Beamer Theme Matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/), for the choice of a beamer theme.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is not use the default colour theme. EVERYBODY uses the blue/white theme. It's boring. So think carefully about using a different theme. That will immediately make your presentation stand out. (unless everyone else is using powerpoint, in which case you already have the upper hand)

For example: `\usecolortheme{beaver}` will immediately make your presentation look different from other beamer presentations. You might want to add `\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=darkred!60!black}` or something similar to your preamble so that bullet points are red rather than blue. (I cannot understand how colour themes fail to redefine that by default...) [this trick comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865581/changing-the-colour-of-textbullet-in-latex-beamer)