# Changing the colour of \textbullet in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

I don't want to use Beamer's standard blue colour theme. I want to use `beaver`, which is deep reds. Everything looks nice, except that if I use `itemize` the bullet points are still blue. Is there a nice way to have the bullets vary with what colour theme I was using? (If I were to opt for a yellowish colour theme, I'd expect the bullets to go yellow too.)

If there isn't, what is the brute force way to change the bullet points red? Or at the very least, make them go back to black again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ... what is the brute force way to change the bullet points red? ...

This works for me:

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red} % all frames will have red bullets

\begin{frame}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
    \item Third item.
    \item Fourth item.
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Awesome. That does work. Unless someone comes up with a neat variable way to do it, this'll be accepted tomorrow.

Comment: @Seamus, putting `\setbeamercolor...` outside the frame causes all frames to have red bullets. See my edit.

Comment: I was asking to have the bullet colour change when I change theme. And I guess I can do that by adding your fix to the `.sty`. And adding a similar line to the yellow theme style file.

Comment: That sounds like a probable solution (I've never tampered with .sty files myself though...).

Comment: beamer colour theme .sty files are literally just lists of `\usebeamercolor` commands...

Comment: Thanks for a cool answer. Somehow I can't find a comprehensive list of everything the `\setbeamercolor` accepts to change.

Comment: How would I go about changing the color for enumerate items? `\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=red}` doesn't work.

Comment: @BruceConnor, I'm not into (La)TeX much these days. Consider posting your question on: http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 30):

In the current (early 2012) version of beamer, you want to use:

```
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=red}
```

instead.

Comment: @cupakob for me this does not work for subitems either. I had to use: `\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=black}`